# How to work with Sprite - Byte Array Assembly x86

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

In the last days, while I'm working on a project, I was introduced to the sprite - Byte Array.

Unfortunately, I didnt find out any kond of information about the sprite which can tell me mote about what is this and how it's works.

I really be pleased if you can give me some information and examples for sprite.

Comment: i've found this (may be helpful): http://www.nondot.org/sabre/graphpro/sprite2.html

Comment: (i will delete this comment in one-two days) what syntax do you learn, masm, nasm or other?

Comment: I'm actucally working with emu8086 at this moment, Althought I thought to move to TASM or MASM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sprite is basically an image with a transparent background color or alpha channel which can be positioned on the screen and moved (usually involving redraw the background over the old position). In the case of an animated sprite, the sprite may consist of several actual images making up the frames of the animation. The format of the image depends entirely on the hardware and/or technology being used to draw or render it. For speed, the dimensions are usually powers of two (8,16,32,64 etc) but this may not be necessary for modern hardware.

Traditionally (read: back in my day), you might have a 320x200x256 screen resolution and a 16x16x256 sprite with color 0 being transparent. Each refresh of the screen would begin with redrawing the background under the sprites, taking a copy of the background under their new position and then redrawing only the visible colors of every sprite in their new position.

With modern hardware, however, it is more efficient to pass data in a format that the driver can handle (hopefully in the graphics accelerator) rather than do everything by hand.

Comment: Thank for the info, but still can you help me with the part of how to really do and print an sprite?

Comment: A simple form is to use the move instruction for to write the color of a single pixel with a calculated offset adress of the screen position into the framebuffer. The segment adress of the framebuffer for the screen resolution of 320x200 with 256 colors for videomode 13h starts at 0A000h in the upper left corner of the screen. The offset address = (y_coordinate * 320) + x_coordinate. Each byte represent one colored pixel. The next step is to copy the colors of a sprite table into the framebuffer.